# Given a Horizontal Derivative Kernel What Would Be the Output Image?

Tags: image-processing, convolution, finite-differences

[image]

Hi, im solving this problem and everything went well until i went and solved the position p(5,3) and i got the  answer of *0*. However, the solution guide  lists the solution  as *150* which is pointed at in blue. I don't understand this since the pixel at the location is 0, meaning we don't have to calculate the solution however the solution says otherwise. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided is correct. Here is why.

To compute the derivative at index(3,5)

```
d(3,5) = value_at(4,5) - value_at(2,5)
d(3,5) = 150 - 0 
d(3,5) = 150
```

Hence the solution provided there is correct. Hope this helps :)